# Translation error? Does Agur in Proverbs 30:3 have knowledge of the Holy or not?

Tags: proverbs

In Proverbs 30:3 most translations translate verse 3 as Agur not having knowledge of the Holy.

In some interlinear translations, the text states that Agur does have the knowledge of the Holy.

See Proverbs 30:3 comparison:

Does know:

- Young's Literal Translation

  > Nor have I learned wisdom, Yet the knowledge of Holy Ones I know.
- International Standard Version

  > I never acquired wisdom, but I know what the Holy One knows.

Does not know:

- King James Bible

  > I neither learned wisdom, nor have the knowledge of the holy.
- English Standard Version

  > I have not learned wisdom, nor have I knowledge of the Holy One.

Which is it?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Welcome to SE-BH. Good question. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding Prov 30:3 is the previous verse, V2 where Argur says that he is uneducated in worldly wisdom.  Let me quote more extensively (my translation):

> (V2) Surely, I am more stupid than [any] man; and do no not have the
> understanding of a man
>
> (V3) Neither have I learned wisdom; nor have the knowledge of holy
> [men]

Thus, Argur is simply expressing his humility and demurring to greater people.  He says this because he is not formally trained/schooled in worldly wisdom and conventional theology.

The second-last word in V3 is קְדֹשִׁ֣ים = "holy" which is a plural masculine adjective.  Thus, it cannot be translated "holy knowledge" because "knowledge" (the previous word) is feminine singular.  Thus, the noun which the "holy" modifies is implied; thus, based on the context (stated above) it must be masculine plural and cannot be "holy one" as this is singular - it must be something like either:

- holy things, or
- holy men

Based on the context, I prefer the latter.  This is reinforced by the implied parallelism with the singular "man" in the previous verse.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there is a translation error involved, as the two different renderings are incompatible.  The question is, which one is right?

**Neither ... Nor**

The issue is this: Hebrew does not have a dedicated word for "neither" or "nor" as English does.  It has the word "not."  The text starts with the "and not," then, in poetic fashion, adds the second line of the couplet with "and."  Translators get to interpret whether that "and" is *disjunctive* (joining two unrelated/unconnected thoughts) or *conjunctive* (linking the two together).

For example, one might say: "I didn't work on Sunday and Monday," and the listener would likely understand that the speaker worked *neither* on Sunday, *nor* on Monday.  Using the neither-nor expression would be much more clear, but in this case, with only the two words, either expression will likely be correctly understood.

However, with a longer phrase, ambiguity increases.  Consider: "I didn't work on Sunday at the time and on Monday."  Did the speaker work on just one day of the two, and not on both? Or did the speaker work on neither day?  It is now less clear, especially since English has the more clear neither...nor option which was not used.

**Hebrew: Not ... And**

Hebrew, on the other hand, doesn't have that option.  The "neither...nor" structure comes from "not...and."

Here's an example from a different text.

> And he brought up Hadassah, that is, Esther, his uncle's daughter:
> **for she had neither father nor mother,** and the maid was fair and beautiful; whom Mordecai, *when her father and mother were dead,* took
> for his own daughter.  (Esther 2:7, KJV)

We know that the bolded part should be *neither...nor* because the same verse says plainly that "her father **and** mother were dead."  However, that "neither...nor" is "not...and" in Hebrew.  It could, of course, be translated as "she did not have father **and** mother," but this is less clear in English--it could mean that she had just *one* of her parents, *not both.*  But the Hebrew intent is not vague, despite lacking the exact equivalent for the English *neither* and *nor*.  The "not...and" construction should be clear enough.

**Proverbs 30:3**

In the verse in question, the "neither...nor" translation is also the best choice.  This is for two reasons: 1) the grammatical application explained above; and 2) the poetic parallel of the two lines in this couplet in Hebrew.  The word "and" joins two lines which are chiastically parallel.

```
And neither I learned wisdom
Nor knowledge of the holy have I.
```

Notice the parallels between "learned" and "knowledge"; and between "wisdom" and "holy."  Notice also that "I" comes both early and late in the sequence.  This is all part of the typical poetic form in Hebrew, often called a chiastic structure, or a chiasmus.  In classic form, one line will be followed by another which repeats back in almost reverse order the same idea but with different words.  There are variations where opposites are juxtaposed in this manner, but it is often the case that parallels are made.

The word "one" or "ones" following "holy" is not in the Hebrew, but might be justified by the fact that the word "holy" is plural in form in the Hebrew--like "holies," which would make it seem noun-like, even though it is an adjective.

### Conclusion

The KJV translation of this verse renders its Hebrew intent most clearly of the examples provided.  The ESV closely follows, though it has added the word "One" to the original text.  The translations with "yet" and "but" seem unsupportable, given the Hebrew.